# CSS for DatePicker-Cell-Popup in GWT

Tags: css, gwt

In my GWT-Application I have a Custom-Table with a DatePicker-Column. Now I have to set the z-index for the Popup. I did this in my form with:

```
.dateBoxPopup {
    z-index:5000;
}
```

Is there an equivalent for the Cell-Popup like .DatePickerCellPopup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you refering to the [DatePickerCell](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/cell/client/DatePickerCell.html) in the CellWidgets?

In case you are: The DatePickerCell uses a [DatePicker](http://www.google.com/codesearch#A1edwVHBClQ/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/datepicker/client/DatePicker.java) and the `DatePicker` uses following CSS classes for styling (use Firebug to check them):

- .gwt-DatePicker { }
- .datePickerMonthSelector { the month selector widget }
- .datePickerMonth { the month in the month selector widget }
- .datePickerPreviousButton { the previous month button }
- .datePickerNextButton { the next month button }
- .datePickerDays { the portion of the picker that shows the days }
- .datePickerWeekdayLabel { the label over weekdays }
- .datePickerWeekendLabel { the label over weekends }
- .datePickerDay { a single day }
- .datePickerDayIsToday { today's date }
- .datePickerDayIsWeekend { a weekend day }
- .datePickerDayIsFiller { a day in another month }
- .datePickerDayIsValue { the selected day }
- .datePickerDayIsDisabled { a disabled day }
- .datePickerDayIsHighlighted { the currently highlighted day }
- .datePickerDayIsValueAndHighlighted { the highlighted day if it is also selected }

You have to specify these css classes with the [@external](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle.html#External_and_legacy_scopes) tag to suppress selector obfuscation

Comment: Thank you for your Answer, but it does not solve my Problem. I Have a main.css and a Table.css with `.dateBoxPopup {
 z-index:2000;
}

.gwt-DatePicker {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top:1px solid #999;
  cursor: default;
  z-index:5000;
}´

Comment: @tobvio: I recommend to use Firebug or Chrome's Developer Tools (Inspect Element) to check the actual css.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately .dateBoxPopup is not applied to the popup of DatePickerCell. Therefore, you need a z-index rule for `.gwt-PopupPanel{ z-index: 15000 }`